# Rails Action Mailer Preview doesnt work because no testing unit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, preview, mailer

When I created my rails app following an online tutorial I made the mistake to add -T.
Since then I have continued to develop my own app on top of this app and I figured out that that -T meant that I dont want to install the testing unit.
I am currently working on my emails but I cant figure out how to preview my emails that I generated using Action Mail generator ( `rails g mailer UserMailer`).
I have added `config.action_mailer.preview_path = "#{Rails.root}/lib/mailer_previews"` to my development.rb file but it doesnt seem to work.
When I visit http://localhost:3000/lib/mailer_previews I get a "No route matches [GET] "/lib/mailer_previews" error and when I try to go to http://localhost:3000/rails/mailers I just get an empty white page.
The email view file "welcome_email.html.erb" I am trying to see is located under the user_mailer folder.
(btc my app is a rails app with a react front end)
Any help is appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you need to set `config.action_mailer.show_previews = true`, it is `false` by default.